# Flycheck Emacs Lisp in Org-mode babel source blocks

Tags: org-mode, flycheck, babel

I want to have Flycheck syntax checking when I am editing Emacs Lisp code in a literal Org-mode file using babel `SRC` blocks. (Using Org's editing buffers with `C-c '`).

However the `flycheck-emacs-lisp` checker predicate has the following to say:

> Ensure that we only check buffers with a backing file. For buffers without a backing file we cannot guarantee that file names in error messages are properly resolved, because `byte-compile-file' emits file names *relative to the directory of the checked file* instead of the working directory. Hence our backwards-substitution will fail, because the checker process has a different base directory to resolve relative file names than the Flycheck code working on the buffer to check.

So whenever I try to launch the checker I get `predicate: nil` in `flycheck-verify-setup`.

This is definitely a drawback in the literate-programming style. Is there a way to work around it so that source blocks can be checked?

Comment: How about entering editing mode with `C-c '` ?

Comment: @manandearth That's indeed what I'm doing. I've edited the question to clarify that.